# Failed to execute goal on project X: Could not resolve dependencies for project X:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact XX:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, spring, maven, jar

so i imported 2 maven projects ! rh and common ! the problem is when building the rg project i get this probleme : 
`[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project param: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.talan.byblos:param:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Could not find artifact com.talan.byblos:commonByblos:jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT ->`

what i get is that the rh project is relying on common dependencies

so here is the common project pom file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.talan.byblos</groupId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <artifactId>commonByblos</artifactId>

 <description>C'est un module qui contient la liste des dto communs des projets</description>

 <name>commonByblos</name>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.5.8.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  </dependency>

  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-security -->
 <!--  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
  </dependency> -->
  <!-- Add JPA support -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
   <version>2.3</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-logging/commons-logging -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.axis</groupId>
   <artifactId>axis</artifactId>
   <version>1.4</version>
  </dependency>
  <!-- Parseur XML -->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.thoughtworks.xstream</groupId>
   <artifactId>xstream</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.9</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
   <version>3.9</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
     <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>xml-apis</groupId>
     <artifactId>xml-apis</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-ooxml-schemas</artifactId>
   <version>3.9</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>org.apache.xmlbeans</groupId>
     <artifactId>xmlbeans</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>

  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
   <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
   <version>3.9</version>
   <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
     <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
     <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
   </exclusions>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
  </dependency>
 
  <dependency>
   <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
   <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
   <version>0.9.0</version>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>

</project>
```

and this is the rh pom

```
    <groupId>com.talan.byblos</groupId>
    <artifactId>rh</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>rh</name>
    <description>RH Microservice</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.4.3.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Common project -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.talan.byblos</groupId>
            <artifactId>commonByblos</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Spring Netflix Eureka for service discovery explicitly -->

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
         <dependency>
        <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
        <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-aop</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Exclude teh default Tomcat connection pool -->
  <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf-spring3</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.zaxxer/HikariCP -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
            <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
            <classifier>all</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.postgresql/postgresql -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>42.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
            <version>3.5</version>
        </dependency>
```

any help please ? 
i ve seen some solutions like add repositories to your settings file and so 
but none worked

Comment: Have you built and installed the common project yet?

Comment: yes i did !and it was built successfully 
[INFO] <<< tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) < compile @ commonByblos <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:run (default-cli) @ commonByblos ---
[INFO] Skipping non-war project
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: If you are running from your ide then I'd suggest going to the common project dir from terminal and running 'mvn install' and then same for the rh one. If that doesn't work go to ${user.home}/.m2/repository/com/talan to see if the jar is there. If it does work then check your ide's maven configuration.

Comment: thank you it worked